# How to write valid phonegap code to run It on android and ios?

Tags: android, cordova

Hello everybody I learn phonegap framework and I have few questions. I want to write app for android and ios. In android I write using Java and JavaScript so If I want to run it on other platform (like ios where is object-C) do I have to depend mostly on JS, move that code to MAC and build ios app??? I dont understand how to use my code in android and iOS... Do I need MAC? Do I need to know xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using cordova you have to use javascript/HTML/Jquery/Jquery Mobile/CSS, everything that you would use for the web.

Regarding the compilation if you have to work with **IOS**, you must have a **MAC** and then compile the project using **xCode**, ***but you do not need to know him well***, you just need to know the process of publication.

For **Android**, you can instead use **Ecplise**.

Comment: I am using android SDK and Eclipse everyday so there is no much problem ;) ... so I need MAC... great... :) ok thanks for answer but is That true that to publish something on ios/xcode i have to be licensed apple developer and have my Developer ID? even for phonegap?

Comment: Yes, you must have the license Apple developer to publish or even just testing on a device.

Comment: ok but If I use Adobe Service to build APP on iOS then do I need that ID also?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop cross-platform on an Android IDE, such as Eclipse then there is no need for a Mac & Xcode outside of testing. However, if you're saying that you already use Xcode and write in Obj-C then have a look at this tutorial to get you started:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/30734/phonegap-tutorial-a-cross-platform-zombie-app

Or this for a JQM/Android example:

http://www.gajotres.net/building-a-native-mobile-app-with-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile-1-4/

Comment: Thanks :) so I can build multi-platform app using Adobe Service but I need apple developer ID only to send that app on app-store or even for testing installation?

Comment: Yes, you need an Apple developer account to upload anything to their App Store or TestFlight services.